# Need to parse SQS message

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-sqs

I am having some trouble parsing my AWS SQS message when I receive a message.

My main issue is that while it seems to be somewhat of a string it also wants to act like an object.

So far, I have just been trying to parse the message so it has been a lot of `console.log()` and `typeof`.

```
sqs.receiveMessage(params, (err, data) => {
 if (err) console.log(err, err.stack); 
 else {
  messages = data; 
  console.log(typeof messages.Messages[2].Body); // #2
  let validMessage = JSON.parse(messages.Messages[2].Body); // #1
  console.log(`validMessage: ${validMessage}`); // Just doesn't print out
  console.log(typeof validMessage); // Errorr with #1 
  console.log(messages.Messages[2]); // gives #3 below
 }     
});
```

## 1:

```
SyntaxError: Unexpected token o in JSON at position 1
at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
```

## 2:

`string`

## 3:

```
{ MessageId: '2afe328d-0b23-4f21-82c5-47563cd994ef',
  ReceiptHandle: 
'AQEB4Giu1whgf6He9cJZVCNBzyfbIPPWlS5HOMLwsyC2lLODJbOudVIdLAx0R9U//XHP9CFr1xhycGzdFXPM1gkHRFf004G1AyqkuB1VPRd/RoQGDcJ9yiKw94b6L7i4VWqbCGdr0Dnz0IMw7ze+C69lE1+TD02L28crHscx+IuWdGKpFq79lOJjpbXfmYv4LP/m1fG3aWyRphKkgtFT/eOCpzqLbGn1Gq6h8RBxo7rexGW5SiNw9F/gVPVTpAWuJolOXv9duAzu8FF7rMnBl2bFjEbLirDtg1RwZtXdG64YsJF2pVwlWrAsx26W06GJocXI',
  `MD5OfBody: '1441a7909c087dbbe7ce59881b9df8b9',`
  `Body: '[object Object]' } `
```

I'm not sure what I am doing wrong, as well as why it is not working right. There are only two properties in the `Body` of the message which are email and token. I want to access both.

As for the expected result, I would expect to be able to access the email by doing `console.log(messages.Messages[i].Body.email)` and it should be equal to `john.doe@example.com`.

Comment: Did you ever find a fix? I'm having the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

To reproduce your situation, I did the following:

- Created an Amazon SQS queue
- Sent a message to the queue using `aws sqs send-message --queue-url ... --message-body foobar`
- Retrieved the message via code

I'm a Python person rather than Node, but it should be the same general idea:

```
import boto3

client=boto3.client('sqs',region_name='ap-southeast-2')

response = client.receive_message(QueueUrl='https://sqs.ap-southeast-2.amazonaws.com/743112987576/stack')
print (response)
print (response['Messages'][0]['Body'])
```

The formatted `response` was:

```
{
    u'Messages': [
        {
            u'Body': 'foobar', 
            u'ReceiptHandle': '...', 
            u'MD5OfBody': '...', 
            u'MessageId': '...'
        }
    ], 
    'ResponseMetadata': {...}
}
```

And the final output was `foobar`.

It is possible that the Node SDK handles things a bit differently, and you might need to convert a string to JSON objects.

Comment: Umm... that just replicates similar to what I have. The issue is you are putting in a string to SQS instead of the object I am trying to use. If you look above you will see where I convert the string to JSON already so that suggestion is mute.

Comment: If the string sent to SQS is a string-version of JSON, then you can use a function to convert the JSON string into an actual object. In Python, the command is `json.loads()`. There's probably an equivalent in Node.

Comment: See my OP with the `JSON.parse()`  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse